# Scrapy error when following links: AttributeError: 'HtmlResponse' object has no attribute 'follow_all'

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am a python and scrapy beginner currently trying to get the ranking for every language / game combination on https://www.twitchmetrics.net/channels/viewership

However, I can't get scrapy to follow the links. I always get an 'HtmlResponse' object has no attribute 'follow_all'  - error.

```
    def parse(self, response):
    all_channels = response.xpath('//h5')
    language_page_links = response.xpath(
        '//div[@class="mb-4"][1]//a//@href').getall()

    for i, channel in enumerate(all_channels, start=1):
        il = ItemLoader(item=LeaderboardItem(), selector=channel)
        il.add_xpath('channel_id', './text()')
        il.add_value('rank_mostwatched_all_all', i)
        yield il.load_item()

    yield from response.follow_all(language_page_links, self.parse)
```

In the last line I will be using a different parser once I get the link-following working. I also tried the example scraper from the scrapy documentation for which I get the exact same error:

```
class AuthorSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'author'

start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/']

def parse(self, response):
    author_page_links = response.css('.author + a')
    yield from response.follow_all(author_page_links, self.parse_author)

    pagination_links = response.css('li.next a')
    yield from response.follow_all(pagination_links, self.parse)

def parse_author(self, response):
    def extract_with_css(query):
        return response.css(query).get(default='').strip()

    yield {
        'name': extract_with_css('h3.author-title::text'),
        'birthdate': extract_with_css('.author-born-date::text'),
        'bio': extract_with_css('.author-description::text'),
    }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation shows that [follow_all](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.follow_all) is new method avaliable only in version 2.0.

You may have to update `scrapy`

```
 pip install --update scrapy
```

Comment: This was it, thank you very much. Initially I didn't use conda-forge to install scrapy and ended up with version 1.6 without realising it